# How to have values for a check box ( 0 or 1) based on if its clicked or not

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, checkbox

This is my first time working with checkboxes (I know, LOL). I just wanted to know if it is possible for me to used a stored porcedure to insert into SQL, based on if the check box was ticked or not.

I have a public void function with parameters, one being "IsAdmin"

I add the parameter like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsAdmin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IsAdmin;
```

On my button, i just say the name of my function, and start adding the values.
Now, if the checkbox is not ticked, the value will be 0. otherwise 1.

Is there some way to say "If ticked, then 1. Else 0."

(to call my function i just say InsertNewUser(). In between the brackets i have the values that will be added. Is this the correct way to insert the value?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what type of project are you using (wpf, asp.net mvc, etc..)?

Comment: Its a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code behind you can check if the `checkbox` is `checked`. Replace the `checkbox` with the actual name of the checkbox from your code

```
if (checkbox.Checked== true)
 IsAdmin=1;
else IsAdmin=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go on the [CheckBox.Checked Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
checkBox1.Checked
```

Comment: Sorry could you ellaborate a bit please.

Comment: i assume you code in WinForms, so you have a Checkbox with a name. And this Checkbox has a property named Checked. It has the values true or false, so you can just leave the variable IsAdmin and assign checkBox.Checked directly or handle it on the ChechedChanged Event

Answer (score 0):

add the checkbock changed event, and there set:

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      IsAdmin=Checkbox1.Checked;
   }
```